# Name of result implying $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2\exp(-n^2)<\int_{1}^{\infty}\nu^2\exp(-\nu^2)d\nu$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I need to use the following inequality:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2\exp(-n^2)<\int_{1}^{\infty}\nu^2\exp(-\nu^2)d\nu\tag{1}$$

What would be the name of a theorem yielding this inequality?

Comment: It's an estimate ^^ The trick stems from
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \,dx \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f|_{[n,n+1]} \|_\infty \int_n^{n+1} \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f|_{[n,n+1]}\|_\infty$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a theorem, simply the fact that the function $x\mapsto x^2\mathrm e^{-x^2}$ is decreasing on $x\geqslant1$ hence, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$u(n)\geqslant\int_n^{n+1}u(x)\mathrm dx,$$ and, summing these, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u(n)\geqslant\int_1^\infty u(x)\mathrm dx.$$ Thus the upper bound in your post is wrong. To get an upper bound, note that the same argument yields $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u(n)\leqslant\int_0^\infty u(x)\mathrm dx=\sqrt\pi.$$

Comment: You can generalise to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathop{\rm ess\,\inf}_{x\in[n,n+1]} f(x) \le \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathop{\rm ess\,sup}_{x\in[n,n+1]} f(x)$$

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the answer.  For the upper bound, I should start from $u(n)\le\int_{n-1}^{n}u(x)\mathrm dx,n=1,2,...$. Right?

Comment: @AlexR.  Thanks for the comments!  What does "ess" stands for?

Comment: @mike Right. Re AlexR's comment, "essinf" is the essential infimum, "esssup" is the essential supremum.

Comment: @Did. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @mike As did said, these are the essential infimum / supremum.
$$\mathop{\rm ess\,sup}_{x\in A} f(x) := \inf_{N\subset A, \mu(N) = 0} \sup_{x\in A\setminus N} f(x)$$
Where $\mu$ is the measure for integration (lebesgue measure). The essential infimum is defined accordingly

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks for the explanation.  I got it.